# autoenv not working on windows 7

Tags: linux, windows, virtualenv

I have installed virtualenv and autoenv on Windows 7 using pip install:

```
pip install virtualenv
pip install autoenv
```

and added a .env file with contents:

```
target_folder/.env
source env/bin/activate
```

I have also setup the same system on Linux Mint 17. When I CD into the target_directory on Linux Mint, autoenv activates. When I CD into the target_directory on Windows 7, nothing happens. Are there any additional steps in setting up autoenv on Windows 7?

Answer (score 3):

On Linux the `autoenv` tool replaces the shell's built in `cd` function with its own `cd` function that enters the environment specified in the .env file.

On Windows unless using Git Bash/msys2/cygwin the `cd` function isn't as easily overridden, and autoenv is basically a shell script, so I'd imagine the reason you aren't seeing the same behavior is that the developers haven't fully implemented a batch/PowerShell version that is tested on Windows.

I am looking at using something like `autoenv` myself, so once I have discovered any new information I'll come back and update this answer. I do believe there is a PowerShell module available that does something similar, if I run into it again I'll post it here.

Comment: were you able to locate the said PowerShell module?

Comment: I didn't find the PowerShell module and I haven't been using Windows for a while, but I did find that Pipenv supports Windows and has the autoenv things pretty much built in (as well as being the best of pip+virtualenv+autoenv all in one). http://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 2):

If anyone's still looking for something like this for PowerShell, I have a module available on [Github](https://github.com/nickcox/ps-autoenv) or via the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ps-autoenv/).

Comment: This was very useful! I ended up creating a fork of it for venvlink!

Answer (score 2):

try ps-autoenv 
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ps-autoenv/0.4

https://github.com/nickcox/ps-autoenv

```
PS> Import-Module ps-autoenv
PS> echo "echo 'whoa'" > project/.autoenv
PS> cd project
```

whoa